# How do I use an existing class with Mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am using a class from a Ruby gem.  I want to store the objects returned by the gem in MongoDB using Mongoid.  I don't want to modify the gem.  What do I need to do to store the objects in MongoDB using Mongoid?

Answer (score 1):

You need a mongo model such as:

```
class X
  include Mongoid::Document
  field Y, type: String
  # etc etc
end
```

and then you need to populate that model from an object you have from that Gem such as:

```
X.create(Gem.output)
```

Now it's stored within mongoid. Without knowing more details I am unable to provide anymore details on any shortcuts, build in conversions that are possible.

**Update based on comments:**

The simplest way to get up and running is just push each Twitter::Tweet into a mongo collection using [dynamic attributes](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Attributes/Dynamic). This allows you to store the complete object within mongodb without mongoid needing to know each and every field.

Here goes:

```
require 'twitter'

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
  config.consumer_secret     = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
  config.access_token        = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
  config.access_token_secret = "YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET"
end
```

We can define a very simple object to represent our stored data. The 'include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic' allows for dynamic fields.

```
class Tweet
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic
end
```

If we were to store the last marriage proposes from Justin Bieber, below is all that is required. Note the use of find_or_create_by to enable us to run this as many times as we like and only create unique records in mongodb:

```
client.search("to:justinbieber marry me", result_type: "recent").take(1).collect{ |tweet| p Tweet.create(tweet) }
=> [#<Tweet _id: 724763808288374784, created_at: "Tue Apr 26 00:55:32 +0000 2016", id_str: "724763808288374784", text: "@justinbieber marry me plz", entities: {"hashtags"=>[], "symbols"=>[], "user_mentions"=>[{"screen_name"=>"justinbieber", "name"=>"Justin Bieber", "id"=>27260086, "id_str"=>"27260086", "indices"=>[0, 13]}], "urls"=>[]}, truncated: false, metadata: {"iso_language_code"=>"en", "result_type"=>"recent"}, source: "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>", in_reply_to_status_id: nil, in_reply_to_status_id_str: nil, in_reply_to_user_id: 27260086, in_reply_to_user_id_str: "27260086", in_reply_to_screen_name: "justinbieber", user: {"id"=>454325860, "id_str"=>"454325860", "name"=>"Brandi Barton", "screen_name"=>"BrandiiBarton", "location"=>"", "description"=>"", "url"=>nil, "entities"=>{"description"=>{"urls"=>[]}}, "protected"=>false, "followers_count"=>413, "friends_count"=>238, "listed_count"=>2, "created_at"=>"Tue Jan 03 21:39:49 +0000 2012", "favourites_count"=>5385, "utc_offset"=>-14400, "time_zone"=>"Eastern Time (US & Canada)", "geo_enabled"=>true, "verified"=>false, "statuses_count"=>8462, "lang"=>"en", "contributors_enabled"=>false, "is_translator"=>false, "is_translation_enabled"=>false, "profile_background_color"=>"131516", "profile_background_image_url"=>"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/720821701/7a6b6beb1d0f66066115cb44cdb7e445.png", "profile_background_image_url_https"=>"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/720821701/7a6b6beb1d0f66066115cb44cdb7e445.png", "profile_background_tile"=>true, "profile_image_url"=>"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/724069168912457728/cIEdUaLk_normal.jpg", "profile_image_url_https"=>"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/724069168912457728/cIEdUaLk_normal.jpg", "profile_banner_url"=>"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/454325860/1460669660", "profile_link_color"=>"7739A6", "profile_sidebar_border_color"=>"000000", "profile_sidebar_fill_color"=>"EFEFEF", "profile_text_color"=>"333333", "profile_use_background_image"=>true, "has_extended_profile"=>true, "default_profile"=>false, "default_profile_image"=>false, "following"=>false, "follow_request_sent"=>false, "notifications"=>false}, geo: nil, coordinates: nil, place: nil, contributors: nil, is_quote_status: false, retweet_count: 0, favorite_count: 0, favorited: false, retweeted: false, lang: "en">]
```

Once created, we get grab it using any search method (find_by, first, etc)

```
Tweet.first
=> #<Tweet _id: 724763808288374784, created_at: "Tue Apr 26 00:55:32 +0000 2016", id_str: "724763808288374784", text: "@justinbieber marry me plz", entities: {"hashtags"=>[], "symbols"=>[], "user_mentions"=>[{"screen_name"=>"justinbieber", "name"=>"Justin Bieber", "id"=>27260086, "id_str"=>"27260086", "indices"=>[0, 13]}], "urls"=>[]}, truncated: false, metadata: {"iso_language_code"=>"en", "result_type"=>"recent"}, source: "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>", in_reply_to_status_id: nil, in_reply_to_status_id_str: nil, in_reply_to_user_id: 27260086, in_reply_to_user_id_str: "27260086", in_reply_to_screen_name: "justinbieber", user: {"id"=>454325860, "id_str"=>"454325860", "name"=>"Brandi Barton", "screen_name"=>"BrandiiBarton", "location"=>"", "description"=>"", "url"=>nil, "entities"=>{"description"=>{"urls"=>[]}}, "protected"=>false, "followers_count"=>413, "friends_count"=>238, "listed_count"=>2, "created_at"=>"Tue Jan 03 21:39:49 +0000 2012", "favourites_count"=>5385, "utc_offset"=>-14400, "time_zone"=>"Eastern Time (US & Canada)", "geo_enabled"=>true, "verified"=>false, "statuses_count"=>8462, "lang"=>"en", "contributors_enabled"=>false, "is_translator"=>false, "is_translation_enabled"=>false, "profile_background_color"=>"131516", "profile_background_image_url"=>"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/720821701/7a6b6beb1d0f66066115cb44cdb7e445.png", "profile_background_image_url_https"=>"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/720821701/7a6b6beb1d0f66066115cb44cdb7e445.png", "profile_background_tile"=>true, "profile_image_url"=>"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/724069168912457728/cIEdUaLk_normal.jpg", "profile_image_url_https"=>"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/724069168912457728/cIEdUaLk_normal.jpg", "profile_banner_url"=>"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/454325860/1460669660", "profile_link_color"=>"7739A6", "profile_sidebar_border_color"=>"000000", "profile_sidebar_fill_color"=>"EFEFEF", "profile_text_color"=>"333333", "profile_use_background_image"=>true, "has_extended_profile"=>true, "default_profile"=>false, "default_profile_image"=>false, "following"=>false, "follow_request_sent"=>false, "notifications"=>false}, geo: nil, coordinates: nil, place: nil, contributors: nil, is_quote_status: false, retweet_count: 0, favorite_count: 0, favorited: false, retweeted: false, lang: "en">
```

We can also get access to embedded documents, such as user for the tweet, without having to do anything other then specific it.

```
Tweet.first.user
=> {"id"=>454325860,
 "id_str"=>"454325860",
 "name"=>"Brandi Barton",
 "screen_name"=>"BrandiiBarton",
 "location"=>"",
 "description"=>"",
 "url"=>nil,
 "entities"=>{"description"=>{"urls"=>[]}},
 "protected"=>false,
 "followers_count"=>413,
 "friends_count"=>238,
 "listed_count"=>2,
 "created_at"=>"Tue Jan 03 21:39:49 +0000 2012",
 "favourites_count"=>5385,
 "utc_offset"=>-14400,
 "time_zone"=>"Eastern Time (US & Canada)",
 "geo_enabled"=>true,
 "verified"=>false,
 "statuses_count"=>8462,
 "lang"=>"en",
 "contributors_enabled"=>false,
 "is_translator"=>false,
 "is_translation_enabled"=>false,
 "profile_background_color"=>"131516",
 "profile_background_image_url"=>"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/720821701/7a6b6beb1d0f66066115cb44cdb7e445.png",
 "profile_background_image_url_https"=>"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/720821701/7a6b6beb1d0f66066115cb44cdb7e445.png",
 "profile_background_tile"=>true,
 "profile_image_url"=>"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/724069168912457728/cIEdUaLk_normal.jpg",
 "profile_image_url_https"=>"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/724069168912457728/cIEdUaLk_normal.jpg",
 "profile_banner_url"=>"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/454325860/1460669660",
 "profile_link_color"=>"7739A6",
 "profile_sidebar_border_color"=>"000000",
 "profile_sidebar_fill_color"=>"EFEFEF",
 "profile_text_color"=>"333333",
 "profile_use_background_image"=>true,
 "has_extended_profile"=>true,
 "default_profile"=>false,
 "default_profile_image"=>false,
 "following"=>false,
 "follow_request_sent"=>false,
 "notifications"=>false}
```

We can use all the usual methods to search and find documents based on the data

```
Tweet.where('user.screen_name': 'BrandiiBarton').first.text
=> "@justinbieber marry me plz"
```

Also, it is worth noting that Mongoid is just a model of the represented data. This means once we have the data into mongodb we could update our mongoid model to only see the data we wanted to (whilst leaving the rest happily in mongodb).

So after we have piped the data in, we could have a different model such as:

```
class TwitterTweet
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in collection:'tweets' # NB: mongoid pluralises class names as the collection name 

  field :text, type: String

  embeds_one :user, class_name:'TwitterUser'
end

class TwitterUser
   include Mongoid::Document

   field :name, type: String
   field :screen_name, type: String

   embedded_in :TwitterTweets
end
```

And we can query the same data, just this time we can only see and access the fields that we have specified.

```
TwitterTweet.first
=> #<TwitterTweets _id: 724763808288374784, text: "@justinbieber marry me plz">
```

We can then open the embedded document like before, but again it scoped to only the elements we defined (the others exist in the db, but are just not visible to this object):

```
TwitterTweet.first.user
=> #<TwitterUser _id: 571ed64a0da75753393f3db7, name: "Brandi Barton", screen_name: "BrandiiBarton">
```

In this object, mongoid prevents us from playing with fields that we should not have visibility of, such as I can not update the number of friends they have.

```
TwitterTweet.first.user.update_attributes(friends_count:30)
=> Mongoid::Errors::UnknownAttribute
```

Where as in the dynamic model where I have unrestricted access to the attributes, I can:

```
Tweet.first.user.update_attributes(friends_count:30)
=> true
```

Comment: I can't modify the class. It is from a third party gem.  Can I still add Mongoid?

Comment: The class above is the MongoID class you will need to define. As for one coming out of your gem, you will not need to alter it. Can I ask with GEM you are using so that I can provide you an example?

Comment: I'd like to save tweets with mongoid using the twitter gem: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/Tweet